# How i can save a big csv file into my arraylist full of objects

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

i have a file that has a lot of data. In this file i don't want to write something but i want to write that data of the file in my array list full of objects. So far i have manage to write only this code:

```
  try{
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data.csv");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  ArrayList<Hotell> part_5= (ArrayList<Hotell>) ois.readObject();
  System.out.println(part_5);
  ois.close();
 }catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
```

But when i am going to excute the programm nothing appears

In the file i hava fields like  id, name of hotel , stars

I think  BufferedReader is okey to use it but i don't know how because i want to save my file into arraylist full of objects

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream` deserializes Object primitives that were written with `ObjectOutputStream`. To read your `.csv` file in and populate your `ArrayList` objects, you are going to have to use something like `BufferedReader`, process the input, and populate your `ArrayList` objects programmatically.